# Depending on the argument passed in url go to specific content type

Tags: 7, nodes

I have a link "Add Details". suppose when I click on the Add Details, I will send arguments to the urls. such as in url "http://localhost/drupal/video" video will be my argument. When I click on "Add Details" link if argument is video then I want to go to "Video content type".

When I click on "Add Details", if argument passed is "image" in url("https://localhost/drupal/image), Then I want to go to "image content type".

When I click on "Add Details" link depending on the argument passed in URL I want to go to specific Content type.

How to achieve this.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use hook_menu in custom module to achieve this using below code !
Change the links of Add Details to "goto/video" means full url will be localhost/drupal/goto/video

```
function yourmodule_menu() {
    $menus['goto/%'] = array(
        'title' => 'Just Redirect',
        'page callback' => 'drupal_redirect_to_content_type',
        'page arguments' => array(1),
        'access arguments' => array('access content'),
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    );
    return $menus;
}

function drupal_redirect_to_content_type($type) {
  drupal_goto("admin/structure/types/manage/" . $type);
}
```

Otherwise,

Instead of above what you can do it directly give Add Details link to admin/structure/types/manage/ . $type instead of drupal/$type

Comment: Is there anything wrong with the code:function drupal_redirect_to_content_type($type) {
  if($type == 'videolibrary'){
  drupal_goto("drupal/node/add/exhibit");
  }
 else{
  drupal_goto("drupal/node/add/section");
 }
 } When I click on the "Add Section Details" which is hyper linked to "http://localhost/drupal/videolibrary" Getting page not found error. sorry If anything is wrong with my coding.

Comment: remove drupal , make it "node/add/exhibit" if you are in localhost then localhost/drupal will become your base path !

Comment: Same page not found error is occuring  with the url showing "http://localhost/drupal/videolibrary"

Comment: See my updated answer ! Change the links of Add Details to "goto/video" means full url will be localhost/drupal/goto/video Clear menu cache after doing changes !

Comment: Did all the things mentioned . But still getting the same page not found error. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Thanks Its working.Forgot to place [goto/%} in hook_menu.